# Convert Celsius to Fahrenheit in EmberJS

Tags: javascript, ember.js, converters

I'm a total beginner with EmberJS and I wanted to begin with an easy example. But it does not seem easy to me at all. I tried to adapt the code of the starter kit and mixed it with the code on the homepage of EmberJS, but it doesn't make sense to me at all.

Here is my app.js

```
App = Ember.Application.create();
var c = 100;
var f = c * 9 / 5 + 32;
App.IndexRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
  model: function() {
    return f;
  }
});
```

And this is my poor index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <title>Ember Starter Kit</title>
  <script src="js/libs/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
  <script src="js/libs/handlebars-1.1.2.js"></script>
  <script src="js/libs/ember-1.5.1.js"></script>
  <script src="js/app.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
  <script type="text/x-handlebars">
    <div>
      <label>Celsius:</label>
      {{input type="text" value=c placeholder="Convert Celsius to Fahrenheit"}}
    </div>
    <hr />
    <div class="text"><span class="celsius">{{ c }}</span> Celsius = <span class="fahrenheit"></span> Fahrenheit!</div>
    </div>
    {{outlet}}
  </script>

  <script type="text/x-handlebars" id="index">
      <div>{{model}}</div>
  </script>

</body>
</html>
```

I've tried {{ c * 9 / 5 + 32 }} but this won't work (in opposite to AngularJS). So, my first approach was definitely wrong. How can I get my app running?

Comment: I'm tempted to say to people to stop using Fahrenheit - but I won't :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Computed Properties](http://emberjs.com/guides/object-model/computed-properties/)

Define your `Model` as an Ember object, or `DS.Model` and use a derived attribute in that.

```
App.Temperature = Em.Object.extend({
  celsius: null,

  faren: function() {
    return this.get('celsius')?this.get('celsius') * 9 / 5 + 32: 0;
  }.property('celsius')
});

App.IndexRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
  model: function() {
    return App.Temperature.create({celsius: 50});
  }
});
```

Now the hadlebars template will have this temperature object as model, you can just use {{faren}} in template and its value will get updated whenever `celsius changes. You can bind to it from the input field.

---

[Handlebars helpers](http://emberjs.com/guides/templates/writing-helpers/)

```
Ember.Handlebars.helper('fh', function(value, options) {
  return (parseInt(value, 10) * 9 / 5 + 32);
});
```

and use it in templates

```
{{fh c}} deg F
```

---

> I've tried {{ c * 9 / 5 + 32 }} but this won't work

The idea is to keep logic and arithmetic out of templates as possible.

Comment: Thanks, works like a charm! This seems all transparent to me. First time that I like Ember :D